# NextFlow: can DAG be statically generated?

Tags: nextflow

I am porting NextFlow scripts in DSL1 to DSL2.  To aid my effort, I would like to generate and view the DAG for each NextFlow / DSL1 script statically (IE, without having to execute each NextFlow script).

QUESTION:  is there a way to generate statically the DAG representation of a NextFlow script?

Comment: The problem is that the execution graph is only inferred at runtime. If your workflow includes some test data, you can use that to create the DAG.

Comment: @Steve:  right.  But based on a few other articles out there, I believe there would be some utility in statically extracting a DAG that has nothing to do with the execution context.

Answer (score 2):

In recent versions of Nextflow, you can skip the execution of all processes to, among other things, generate a DAG without having to really run your pipeline script. You can see the commit message [here](https://github.com/nextflow-io/nextflow/commit/aa8f1aa4b5fb39da7921df04f72840fbbcb47912). Check the snippet below for en example:

```
nextflow run nf-core/rnaseq -profile test -preview -with-dag --outdir output_folder
```

You'll find an HTML file for the DAG inside the `output_folder/pipeline_info` folder. I'm not sure how it will work with DSL1, and it may not be available depending on your Nextflow version.

It's important to mention that Steve is correct. The real/precise DAG will be decided at runtime depending on some situations that may change depending on your input data, parameters, and so on. For example, if all your samples are of low quality, and your process `FOO` only accepts high-quality samples, this process won't generate any instances and your data will follow a different path.

Comment: Running `NXF_VER=23.05.0-edge nextflow -preview -with-dag foo.dag foo.nf` results in an error:  *Unknown option: -preview -- Check the available commands and options and syntax with 'help'*

Comment: You missed the `run` command in your command line. `-preview` is an option of `run`.

Comment: Thx!  That worked.  However, note result:  *WARN: Failed to render DAG file: /path/to/foo.dag*.  Are there other pre-conditions for generating DAG with `-preview`?

Comment: What is `.dag`?  Nextflow uses the extension to guess what format you want your DAG in. `.dag` is not supported. Try with `.dot` or `.png`, for example.

Comment: `foo.dot` works!  Thx!